# node.js REQUEST auth hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, request, digest

I am using npm REQUEST for a simple http call. There is ambiguity (at least for me) as to what the hash requirement means. From [the documentation](https://github.com/mikeal/request#http-authentication) I see I need to make a chained function call:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
```

The fine print says "...If passed as an option, auth should be a hash containing values username, password..."

Could someone kindly explain the hashing process? Is it something like this?

```
cypto.createHash('md5').update('fake_username').digest('hex')
```

Here is the full code sample I am working on in nodejs. I get a 401 error

```
var request = require('request')
var cypto = require('crypto')

var unhash = cypto.createHash('md5').update('fake_username').digest('hex')
var pwhash = cypto.createHash('md5').update('fake_password').digest('hex')

request.get('<URL HERE>', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
    else {
        console.log('Response code: ', response.statusCode)
    }
}).auth(unhash,pwhash,false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If passed as an option, auth should be a hash containing values username, password` part is referring to the second example in the readme:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
```

Here 'hash' means 'object'. It has nothing to do with cryptographic hashing.